# customize Bibtex citation and bibliography

Tags: bibtex, natbib

Using Bibtex and Natbib-package, I would like to have a few changes:

citation style

- (numbering) ==> (author et al., year; author et al., year; etc.) as citation style

bibliography style

- no numbering
- several authors ==> author et al. (year)
- quotation marks for title and title customization (is not taken as written in the .bib file)
- customize the journal details

I know that BiblaTex would be the way to go for extended customization, but as long as the majority of journals used Bibtex I'd rather stick with Bibtex and alter the things I like.
Thanks.

Comment: Try `custom-bib` package. It provides the [`makebst`](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/custom-bib/makebst.pdf) script for creating *personalized styles* `.bst`.

Comment: I'd look at `\bibliographystyle{apalike}`, which is close to what you're asking for along with `natbib`. If not, I agree with @skpblack on `custom-bib`, which is pretty easy in interactive mode.

Answer (score 5):

Before studying how to customize bibliography styles either by creating own .bst files or changing to BibLaTex+biber I recommend looking through these bibliography styles here:

- http://www.mackichan.com/index.html?techtalk/632.htm~mainFrame
- http://www.univie.ac.at/nuhag-php/bibtex/bibstyles.pdf
- http://www.reed.edu/cis/Help/LaTeX/bibtexstyles.html
- http://www.cs.stir.ac.uk/~kjt/software/latex/showbst.html

Surely, there is something that suits you - at least more than writing your own .bst-file.