# Natbib produces different output than expected

Tags: bibtex, natbib

I'm preparing a submission to a journal that expects citations in the format [Author(year)]. Based on the examples in, for example, [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/204311), `abbrvnat` seems to fit my requirements. Unfortunately, citations appear differently in my example.

My document looks as follows:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[square]{natbib}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{ref.bib}
  @book{Knu86,
    author = {Knuth, Donald E.},
    year = {1986},
    title = {The \TeX book},
  }
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

Text including citation \cite{Knu86}.

\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat}
\bibliography{ref}

\end{document}
```

I'd expect the following output:

[image: Expected output]

Instead, running pdfLaTeX and bibTeX produces the following result:

[image]

What can I do to achieve the expected output?

I'm open to switching to Biblatex, but the solution [presented here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/35308) formats citations as `[Knu86]` instead of `[Knuth(1986)]`. I'd be interested in customizing Biblatex to fit my needs, but what I don't understand is why `abbrvnat` doesn't already do what I expect. Clearly, I end up with a different result than every example of `abbrvnat` I can find.

Comment: I'm open to switching to Biblatex, but the solution presented in the linked question formats citations as [Knu86] instead of [Knuth(1986)]. I'd be interested in customizing Biblatex to fit my needs, but what I don't understand is why `abbrvnat` doesn't already do what I expect. Clearly, I end up with a different result than every example of `abbrvnat` I can find.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution consists in *not* loading the `natbib` package.

[image]

```
\documentclass[]{article}
%\usepackage[square]{natbib}  % don't load the natbib package

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{ref.bib}
  @book{Knu86,
    author = {Knuth, Donald E.},
    year = {1986},
    title = {The \TeX book},
  }
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

Text including citation \cite{Knu86}.

\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat}
\bibliography{ref}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! Some background information I found: `abbrvnat` has a different meaning when loading natbib. The bibliography styles `abbrv` and `abbrvnat` are different when natbib is not loaded. When natbib _is_ loaded, `abbrvnat` refers to a natbib-compatible version of `abbrv`, not `abbrvnat`.

Comment: @user3364120 - I'm not sure I follow your comment. I'd describe the situation as follows: The `abbrvnat` bibliography style writes a string such as `Knuth(1986)` to the optional argument of each `\bibitem` in the `.bbl` file; this happens whether or not `natbib` is loaded. Then, if `natbib` *is not* loaded, the contents of the optional argument are written out as such, i.e., without modification, for each `\cite` instruction and at the start of each formatted bib entry. Conversely, if `natbib` *is* loaded, either an authoryear-style or a numeric-style citation label is generated.